# Can I modify a file inside osgi bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, karaf

Is it possible to modify a file inside OSGi bundle (the bundle is deployed to apache karaf) ?
In other words, I want to marshall a java object into xml file in a deployed bundle.
Is this possible??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The JAR file format is immutable, if you want to modify a file inside it then you need to create a new JAR.

Since this is OSGi you can then update the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any helpfull link showing how can I apply your solution?